# Best ways to store a large number of documents and be able to search their contents

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I am looking for some suggestions on the best way to store a very large number of documents and be able to freetext search on their contents.

I'm working in PHP and MySQL. I am on a Windows host, but it's shared hosting so I don't have access to the Windows indexing service. Hence the question.

I was considering using the COM interface to open uploaded documents, read their contents into a longtext field, and then create a fulltext index on it. Perhaps someone can point me in another direction?

Comment: Have you considered something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Comment: Will need more info.  What type of documents?

Comment: Hi joe, i'm not sure if hostgator shared hosting allow it, will check

Comment: [`Sphinx`](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is another alternative I have good experiences with.

Comment: Yeah again I dont think they allow it on shared hosting maybe i'm gonna have to bite the bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MySQL Fulltext Search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html
It was made pretty much for your case.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that option but each document will be at least a couple of pages so db bloat will be massive.

Comment: Please specify approximate size of the documents and approximate number of the documents, so that we could provide a better answer. MySQL can handle pretty massive amounts of data. If it's not suitable, you can also consider dedicated search engines like Lucene, or as @Wrikken mentioned Sphinx.

Comment: One great thing about MySQL Fulltext search is that it's pretty easy to try out and benchmark with very little effort.

Comment: Well my hosting won't allow me to install ANYTHING at the moment so MySql seems to be my only option being on shared hosting, documents are normal CV size, no more than 500K each(and thats the MAX)

Comment: 500K each in what format? What is the document size once it's converted into plain text (before loading into the database)?

Comment: DOC,PDF,TXT, RTF will be the main ones

Comment: This means that the documents will be much smaller when they are converted into plain text. With under one million rows, your search should be pretty fast. Even based on this old review: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/files/presentations/EuroOSCON2006-High-Performance-FullText-Search.pdf

Comment: Thanks artem, i'll do that then, I was going to have user data in one table then reference the CV table which would simply have a userref and CV text in it, I just was worried about perfermance

Comment: I'll leave this open for now but i'll tick it tomorrow morning if nobody comes up with a better one for my environment

Comment: One more comment. If you try out the fulltext search, remember to check MySQL EXPLAIN to make sure that the fulltext index is actually being used. Under certain circumstances MySQL does not guess that it should use the index. Also boolean mode tends to be faster.

Comment: You're better off changing your hosting company or getting a dedicated server and running solr or sphinx.  MySql fulltext is rarely very useful, imo.  Also with mysql fulltext you have to use MyIsam and you cannot have foreign-keys, killing any referential integrity you intend on having.  If your application is dealing with a lot of documents/data, then shared hosting/hostgator is the actual problem that you need to solve, in my opinion.

Comment: I should mention why I don't think mysql fulltext is very useful.  It is because the search algorithm is not too flexible and the scoring is the same.  It might be fast enough, but the relevancy of the results might be disappointing.

Comment: Evan: MySQL 5.6 got full text search working with innodb. Should address a lot of your concerns. You are right that depending on your case a dedicated search solution could be good, but if you already have MySQL, trying out the full text search there might be the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4219-PHP-Search-files-in-a-directory-for-a-given-text.html) to do what you want

Comment: thats kind of what I need but the trouble is I could be doing thousands of these searches a day perhaps through 100,000-1 million documents so a file system based solution wouldnt work

Comment: yeah thats a powerfull class to search the files and their contents

Comment: I'll download it and take a look

Comment: i have some solution's  you can mix this with a class and make an object to works better in big scaled project